# Can the mean and variance of X be extracted from this joint probability?

Tags: probability-distributions, means, variance

If we have the joint distribution function:
$\Large f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{\exp{\frac{(36x²-24xy+ 25y^2 − 120x − 2y + 121)}{-1512}}}{55\pi}$

Can we know the mean and variance of X? How?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a multivariate normal distribution, more specifically yours is bivariate. In that case the density funcction is of the following form:
    $$
 \begin{aligned}
 f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Y\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2(1 - \rho^2)}[ \frac{(x - \mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} + \frac{(y - \mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} - \frac{(x - \mu_X)(y - \mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} ])
 \end{aligned}
 $$
    We have $\rho$ as the correlation between the RVs $X$ and $Y$ where $\sigma_X, \sigma_Y > 0$ and
    $$
 \begin{aligned}
 \textbf{mu} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \mu_X \\ \mu_Y
 \end{bmatrix}, \ 
 \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_X^2 & \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y \\ \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y & \sigma_Y^2
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{aligned}
 $$ 
The rest is just a bit of algebra and factorization etc.

Comment: Many thanks for that insight, but I still can't fit it to that form, do I have to integrate to find marginal of X and then get mean and variance?

Comment: Well integrating works as well, you can try and do it that as an exercise. I personally prefer the method I mentioned above. A further hint would just be: \\                                                                                                                       $$
 \begin{aligned}
 36x^2 - 120x & = 36(x - \frac{5}{3})^2 - 100 \\
 25y^2 - 2y & = 25(y - 0.04)^2 - 0.2^2
 \end{aligned}
 $$                                                                                                                    The rest should really follow on straightforwardly.